# Switch to an older installed version of Spotify with homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, spotify

I installed Spotify with brew (on mac) and Spotify updated. I wish to revert to the version it was before (1.1.57.443). How can I do that, since the switch command is no longer supported?